# WFS features and vector layer

Tags: polygon, openlayers, wfs

I try do load WFS layer to my openlayers application according to this tutorial [enter link description here](https://www.acuriousanimal.com/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter03_07_query_wfs.html)

Features from WFS layer are displaying on the map, but i discover that they are not belong to the Vector Layer, which i've created. This layer is empty. What did i wrong?

```
// Polygons
function styl_warstwy() {
    return [
        new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: [ 51, 165, 255 ,1],
                width: 2,
                //lineDash: [4,8],
                //lineDashOffset: 6
                }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                   color: 'rgba(51,165,255,0.25)'
                })
            })
    ];
}

var vectorLoader = function(extent, resolution, projection) {
        var url = 'http://mapy.fotoraporty.pl:8080/geoserver/archiwalne_webGIS/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=archiwalne_webGIS:gmina_result&maxFeatures=2500&outputFormat=application%2Fjson' +
            '&srsname=EPSG:4326&bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
        $.ajax(url).then(function(response) {
            var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
            var features = format.readFeatures(response,
            {featureProjection: projection});
            source.addFeatures(features);
        });
    };
      
var loadFeatures = function(response) {
        var features = vectorSource.readFeatures(response);
        vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
      };

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        loader: vectorLoader,
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
      });

 var vector_kml = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    title: "Gminy",
    style: function(feature) {
            style.getText().setText(feature.get('JPT_NAZWA_'));
            return style;
    },
 });
```

Comment: WFS using Lat/Lon for EPSG:4326 while OpenLayers uses Lon/Lat so try replacing `extent.join` with `[extent[1], extent[0], extent[3], extent[2]].join`

Comment: It was right. WFS features display on map, but they belong to the "undefined" vector layer instead of "vector_kml".

Comment: In your AJAX call you are adding features to `source` source, it probably should be `vectorSource.addFeatures(features);`

Comment: @TomazicM thanks for help!